# Between group analysis for ranked data in spss

Tags: references, spss, ranking

I have ranked data where participants were asked to rank 8 choices from 1-8.  The data is in spss and is in the wide format, where each choice is its own variable (column). There can be no ties. I used the Friedman ANOVA to determine if there is a significant difference in ranks, and there is.

However, I am unsure how to determine if there are significant differences between how 4 groups (n's = 300, 290, 180, 150) ranked the choices.

I had read where I could used a repeated measures ANOVA and tried that but it failed to run the Box's test of equality of covariance matrices. Since I am interested in multivariate analysis this is an issue as I understand it. And as I expected, given the data there are significant correlations between variables. So that was a fail.

Is there a test I can use in SPSS? I do not know R.

Is there a potential to run a generalized linear model?  If so, can anyone recommend a good resource on how to run these models (step by step would be great)?

I was also thinking of ordinal regression, however my data doesn’t seem to fit. Is it allowable to look at each variable (column) separately in ordinal regression to see how the 4 different groups ranked each choice?